# Why does find_each not return the actual AR object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

When I try to just do a vanilla `find_each` it keeps returning `nil` even though there are objects/records it should be acting on.

```
[28] pry(main)> Node.find_each do |node|
[28] pry(main)* end  
  Node Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "nodes".* FROM "nodes"   ORDER BY "nodes"."id" ASC LIMIT 1000
=> nil
[29] pry(main)> Node.all.find_each do |node|
[29] pry(main)*   node
[29] pry(main)* end  
  Node Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "nodes".* FROM "nodes"   ORDER BY "nodes"."id" ASC LIMIT 1000
=> nil
[31] pry(main)> Node.count
   (0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "nodes"
=> 2
[32] pry(main)> Node.find_each do |node|
[32] pry(main)*   puts node
[32] pry(main)* end  
  Node Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "nodes".* FROM "nodes"   ORDER BY "nodes"."id" ASC LIMIT 1000
#<Node:0x007fd49ffbc680>
#<Node:0x007fd49ffbc388>
=> nil
```

How do I get `find_each` to simply output all the objects for that model just like `Node.all` does and why does it just output what seems like the ID of the AR object for each node, only when I do a `puts node`?

```
[35] pry(main)> Node.all
  Node Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "nodes".* FROM "nodes"
=> [#<Node id: 85, name: "House Fire 2", family_tree_id: 57, user_id: 57, media_id: 228, media_type: "Video", created_at: "2015-05-15 00:20:26", updated_at: "2015-05-20 01:06:34", circa: nil, is_comment: nil, cached_votes_total: 0, cached_votes_score: 0, cached_votes_up: 0, cached_votes_down: 0, cached_weighted_score: 0, cached_weighted_total: 0, cached_weighted_average: 0.0>,
 #<Node id: 86, name: "10PP Form Video", family_tree_id: 57, user_id: 57, media_id: 229, media_type: "Video", created_at: "2015-05-15 01:26:28", updated_at: "2015-05-22 20:35:58", circa: nil, is_comment: nil, cached_votes_total: 1, cached_votes_score: 1, cached_votes_up: 1, cached_votes_down: 0, cached_weighted_score: 1, cached_weighted_total: 1, cached_weighted_average: 0.0>]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
> Node.find_each do |node|
> end 
 => nil
```

In this case, the nil is from the definition of this block; not the result of `Node.find_each`.

Try printing out something in the block as follows:

```
> Node.find_each do |node|
>  puts node.id
> end
```

That will print out the 2 ids.

To print out all the objects:

```
> Node.find_each do |node|
>  puts node.inspect
> end
```

Comment: Ok the `node.inspect` worked. But how would I then assign the results of the entire block to variable? e.g. say I wanted to set `nodes = Node.find_each do ....`. How can I do that?

Comment: Doesn't `Node.all` do what you want? Make sure you are using `find_each` for the right purpose: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_each

Comment: Well, I am trying to, in a performant way, load all the objects from that model in my DB into a variable. I like the idea of doing it in batches, rather than just a vanilla `.all` dump. So that's why I was drawn to `.find_each`.